# Can't make FirefoxOS run an app on firefox desktop

Tags: firefox-os, gaia

In [instructions how to a FirefoxOS Email App in Firefox](https://github.com/mozilla-b2g/gaia/tree/master/apps/email#step-3-run-gaia-e-mail) there is a step:

> Start the b2g-desktop instance to serve the e-mail app on port 8080.

How can I do that exactly?

I tried:

- [Download b2g and run it](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Firefox_OS/Building_the_B2G_desktop_client): it behaves as an emulator (opens a separate screen). I want to see the app in my browser instead.
- Google around how to run "FirefoxOS apps on Firefox". Nothing.

How can I make GAIA app run on my desktop Firefox? I am trying to make it work on Linux amd64 firefox 35.

Thanks!